# Formats for Attribute Mapping & Attribute Conditioning in the Workload identity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, okta, workload-identity

I have created an Oauth Server and defined custom scope and claims in the configuration.
On the access token (JWT), I see scope is being defined as

```
"scp": [
    "default_google_scope"
]
```

I am trying to set an integration between OIDC and GCP workload identity configuration  using tutorial :

- https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#oidc_1
- https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-workload-identity-federation-with-okta-90c05b985b17

I am not following what should be the format for attribute mapping and conditions?

[image: Workoad identity configs]

Comment: Can you share what setup and expected outcome for this? This docs might help you regarding [Attribute mappings](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation#mapping)

Comment: Do you want a mapping or a condition? As mapping you must say to Google Cloud where to find the email in the source token. Then you can accept token under conditions.

Comment: Adding more context on the setup : 
What I am trying to do : Trying to access a file on GCS bucket using a python application.  
As part of the Setup : 
1- I have OAuth server in Okta with Claim and Scope Define 
2- I have Workload Identity Fed setup with Okta as OIDC provider ( from step 1)
3- Have setup right IAM Policy, Service accounts etc as specified in the original post

I understand Google token and Okta tokens need to be checked for validity and Attribute mapping and conditions can help to do the same. 

I am struggling to  follow the documentation and apply it to my use case

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Part I am struggling with is the syntax that I should use for mapping and conditions. This is more of a POC so even if I assume there is no condition, what will be my mapping then based on?  my claims and scope? and if my access token spits out the token with scope as "default_gcp_scope" what should be my mapping condition.

Comment: You haven't scope because you haven't access token exchanged, it's only based on Identity Token (JWT). It's a JSON, and you need, at least, to map the token email principal with the google.subject. You can add other mapping if relevant. The condition are the same: you can have custom claim in your JWT, the condition are here to check if the custom claim (or not custom in fact) are OK or KO.